# Use a Canny effect on an image with Delphi or displaying borders

Tags: delphi

first, thanks for the incoming help you could give to me ! I'm searching a solution for applying an effect on an image/BitMap. I wanted something, a library or an API that can help to apply an canny effect or any other effect that can enlight the borders from an object like a parallelepiped rectangle or something else. Does anyone has some clue to achieve this task ? I was thinking that OpenCV could help me but I'm not sure. Thanks for everything

Comment: Doing classic edge-detection is trivial, and you don't need any library for it. I have written such functions several times -- you only need a few lines of code. However, I suspect you are looking for Canny algorithms in particular? If so, this is probably a question seeking library recommendations, which is off-topic at SO.

Comment: I think that doing an edge-detection is sufficient for what I want to do. Do you have a Doc/wiki or a GitHub with some explanation or tutorial on this code? Thank you, appreciate it !

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! You can search google to find a lot of edge-detection algorithm and their merit or pitfall. Once you select one looking good for what you have to do, try to implement it and then when you are stuck, ask a new question specific to that, showing what you have done, and what are your problems.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a classic edge-detection routine is simple.

The following example compares each pixel with the one to the right and with the one below it, so you get both vertical and horizontal edge detection.

```pascal
function EdgeDetect(ABitmap: TBitmap): TBitmap;

  function PixelDist(const L, R: TRGBQuad): Double;
  begin
    Result :=
      Sqrt(
        Sqr(L.rgbRed/255 - R.rgbRed/255) +
        Sqr(L.rgbGreen/255 - R.rgbGreen/255) +
        Sqr(L.rgbBlue/255 - R.rgbBlue/255)
      );
  end;

  function DistGrey(const X, R, B: TRGBQuad): TRGBQuad;
  var
    Level: Byte;
  begin
    Level := EnsureRange(
      Round(255 * (PixelDist(X, R) + PixelDist(X, B)) / Sqrt(3)),
      0,
      255);
    Result.rgbBlue := Level;
    Result.rgbGreen := Level;
    Result.rgbRed := Level;
    Result.rgbReserved := 0;
  end;

var
  S, Sp, T: PRGBQuad;
  y: Integer;
  x: Integer;
begin

{$POINTERMATH ON}
  ABitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;

  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Result.SetSize(ABitmap.Width - 1, ABitmap.Height - 1);
    Result.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    S := ABitmap.ScanLine[0];
    for y := 0 to ABitmap.Height - 2 do
    begin
      Sp := ABitmap.ScanLine[y + 1];
      T := Result.ScanLine[y];
      for x := 0 to ABitmap.Width - 2 do
        T[x] := DistGrey(S[x], S[x + 1], Sp[x]);
      S := Sp;
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
{$POINTERMATH OFF}

end;
```

This transforms

[image: Picture of a dog.]

into

[image: Edge-detected version of the previous picture.]

Please note that this routine creates a new `TBitmap` object. It is the responsibility of the caller to free this.

Comment: I expected you would choose a frog for the example but it's still nice ;-)